# StreamReader stop program on readLine

Tags: c#, streamreader

I am trying to connect to the server and read data through StreamReader. The ReadLine method stops program execution after the server finishes sending data and starts waiting for a response from the client.

For example:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(sslStream);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sslStream);
string response;
writer.WriteLine("HI!");
while((response = reader.ReadLine()) != null){
    Console.WriteLine(response);
}

Output:
S: somedata1
S: somedata2
S: *no data*
(Program does nothing, no exit codes or thg else)
```

After that, nothing happens, the debugger does not go further along the lines. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
while((response = reader.ReadLine()) != null){
    Console.WriteLine(response);
}
```

with

```
while(!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = reader.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

It is also good practice to wrap StreamReader and StreamWriter in using block like this:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sslStream)) {
  // ... your code
}
```

After `using` block is finished it will dispose the stream automatically. Do it for all classes that implement `IDisposable`.